# How to update a setting on the _doc type using elasticsearch.net/nest 6.x

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Specifically what I'm trying to achieve through Elasticsearch.Net and NEST 6.x APIs is the [example of setting dynamic=strict on the _doc type shown in this article using JSON](https://cambium.consulting/articles/2018/2/20/mappings-aliases-and-index-templates-three-of-our-favorite-elasticsearch-features).

The setting at the type level is also mentioned in the [official docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html#dynamic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send this request with the high level client using

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

var putMappingResponse = client.Map<object>(m => m
    .Index("testindex1")
    .Type("_doc")
    .Dynamic(DynamicMapping.Strict)
);
```

which will send the following request

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/testindex1/_doc/_mapping
{
  "dynamic": "strict"
}
```

The end result will be that of [strict behaviour for dynamic fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html) for the `_doc` type in the `testindex1` index.

Answer (score 1):

I dipped into the low-level client to effect this solution, whereas when I posted the question I was searching in the high level client.

```
using Nest; // C# 

var pd = PostData.String("{ \"dynamic\": \"strict\" }");
var result = client.LowLevel.IndicesPutMappingPost<PutMappingResponse>(indexNm, "_doc", pd);
```

where the `client` variable is an ElasticClient instance.
and `indexNm` variable is a string containing "testindex1"

Results in

```
{
    "testindex1": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "_doc": {
                "dynamic": "strict",
```

where I see `dynamic: strict` has been added to the `_doc` type mapping as expected.